# What's the best way to get the hostname from the env hash in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, hostname, env

I'm writing an [OmniAuth dynamic provider](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Dynamic-Providers) and in the callback I need to get the current hostname (the app works in several different hostnames). I don't have the request object, just a big env hash. I found this hash contains an entry, env["SERVER_NAME"], with the hostname, but I'm not sure if that's a stable entry or it may change depending on the web server or stuff like that.

I also found the hostname buried in env["action_dispatch.routes"] in the member variable @host.

Any ideas what's the best or canonical way to get the hostname at this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app is not in production yet, but so far the the private beta, using `env["SERVER_NAME"]` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

In a rails controller, you can simply use:

```
request.host
```

Though I'm not sure if that sources anything different from what you already looked at. This works fine for me in a Rails 3.1 app I'm working on.

Comment: I'm not a Rails controller, I'm implementing the setup method for an OmniAuth dynamic provider.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but I suggest trying to reference request.host in your code there and see if it works. I have to admit, I'm not sure which variables are created inside Rack for this process.

Comment: yeah, I tried that, it didn't work. For now I'm using env["SERVER_NAME"] but I haven't tested in production yet.